# Data masking implementation in SQL Server 2012. How to control access to users?

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012, data-masking

Setup: SQL Server 2012

Currently, we are working on a project to mask the data in Prod/dev/UAT systems and we are in the process of defining what is considered as sensitive /non-sensitive according to company policies.It would take another month before all the fields are finalized.Before that, I would like to take some time to find out methods to figure it out.

After reading some material, it has been clear, I could use any of the masking techniques such as scrambling, deleting a portion of text, repeating character masking, masking table etc. But once, one of these methods are applied, it would be permanent on that database and it would not be possible to decrypt that field.

But I would like to show masked values to only some users based on the access and revoke it the same way. Could someone help me, is there a way this could be achieved and how?

Users access the data via SSRS reports and Cube directly.

Note: It would not be possible to upgrade to SQL 2016 for another year or so.

Answer (score 0):

DbDefence implements data masking for SQL Server R2 and higher.

Implementation is similar to dynamic masking, but unmasked values never appear in the database files or backups (unlike with Microsoft's implementation). You may set it up in several ways:

- All applications except selected see masked data.
- All logins except selected see masked data.
- Application may see unmasked data after a special SQL statement.

It works with Cube, SSRS and other tools.
More about it: https://www.database-encryption.com/support/dbdefence-documentation/data-masking-SQL-Server.html
In general, the free version of DbDefence available for small databases.

I'm associated with the vendor.